# Pass Parameters From Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Repeater`, and for each item in my `Repeater` I have a button to fire a CommandEvent. I need to pass an object as a parameter when my button is clicked.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the Repeater's [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and pass the object as [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument.aspx).

[Here](http://dotnetrush.blogspot.com/2006/12/using-repeater-itemcommand.html) is an example.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteComment" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("CommentID") %>></asp:LinkButton>
```

codebehind

```
protected void rptComments_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
    if(e.CommandName.ToLower().Equals("deletecomment")) {
        clsComment comment = new clsComment("mediadb");
        comment.CommentID = int.Parse(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandArgument);
        comment.DeleteRecord();
        rptComments.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The `CommandArgument` will be passed as string, so ensure that you've converted it in the first place to avoid possibly wrong implicit conversions.

You should use the key-parameter of your class, for example an ID. If you need the instance, create it in the `ItemCommand` event-handler.

Comment: Even though `RepeaterCommandEventArgs.CommandArgument` is `Object`, `Button.CommandArgument` property is `System.String`.  Therefore it is probably most robust to convert any data you want to pass (to System.String) to avoid bugs from implicit conversion.  @tomcamara are you using a parameter type that can be converted to System.String?

Comment: @pseudocoder right, Button.CommandArgument is string :) fixed my answer.

Comment: You should only pass the key parameter of your class, for example an ID.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of object it is? Button has CommandArgument property. You can save string values in it.

Comment: is an object from my user class.